# Create a dictionary that is associated with lists and update this through a loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I am using python2.7. I have a file which contains a chromosomal location and an experiment ID. I have got this information stored at the moment in two lists:

```
unique_locations - containing a single value for each location
location_exp - containing lists of [location, experiment]
```

The reason I have not used a dictionary is that there are multiple locations found in multiple experiments - i.e this is a many-many relationship.

I would like to find out on how many experiments each location is found. I.e get a list like:

```
[
    [location1, [experiment1, experiment2, experiment3]], 
    [location2, [experiment2, experiment3, experiment4]]
                                                             ]
```

etc.

As the lengths of the lists are different I have failed using an enumerate(list) loop on either lists. I did try:

```
location_experiment_sorted = []
for i, item in enumerate(unique_experiment):
    location = item[0]
    exp = item[1]
    if location not in location_experiment_sorted:
        location_experiment_sorted.append([location, exp])
    else:
        location_experiment_sorted[i].append(exp)
```

Amongst other things. I have also tried using a dictionary which relates to a list of multiple experiments. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you can simply sort your `location_exp` list and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Not sure if I understood the situation correctly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do understand you correctly
(if locations can be used as dict keys)

you could do:

```
location_experiments={}
for location, experiment in location_exp:
    location_experiments.setdefault(location,[]).append(experiment)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try defaultdict, ie:

```
from collections import defaultdict

unique_locations = ["location1", "location2"]
location_exp = [
    ("location1", "experiment1"),
    ("location1", "experiment2"),
    ("location1", "experiment3"),
    ("location2", "experiment2"),
    ("location2", "experiment3"),
    ("location2", "experiment4")
]

location_experiment_dict = defaultdict(list)
for location, exp in location_exp:
    location_experiment_dict[location].append(exp)

print(location_experiment_dict)
```

will print-out:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    'location2': ['experiment2', 'experiment3', 'experiment4'],
    'location1': ['experiment1', 'experiment2', 'experiment3']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run this, so apologies if it fails.
if you say it's a list of lists like [ [location, experiment], [location, experiment] ] then:

```
locationList = {}
for item in unique_experiment:
    location = item[0]
    exp = item[1]
    if location not in locationList:
        locationList[location] = []
        locationList[location].append(exp)
    else:
        locationList[location].append(exp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another working example, using built-in `dict` and `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> d = {}
>>> location_exp = [
    ("location1", "experiment1"),
    ("location1", "experiment2"),
    ("location1", "experiment3"),
    ("location2", "experiment2"),
    ("location2", "experiment3"),
    ("location2", "experiment4")
]
>>> for k,v in groupby(location_exp, itemgetter(0)):
        d.setdefault(k,[])
        d[k].extend([loc for _, loc in v])


[]
[]
>>> d
{'location2': ['experiment2', 'experiment3', 'experiment4'], 'location1': ['experiment1', 'experiment2', 'experiment3']}
>>> 
>>> d2 = {}
>>> location_exp2 = [
    ("location1", "experiment1"),
    ("location2", "experiment2"),
    ("location3", "experiment3"),
    ("location1", "experiment2"),
    ("location2", "experiment3"),
    ("location3", "experiment4")
]
>>> for k,v in groupby(location_exp2, itemgetter(0)):
        d2.setdefault(k,[])
        d2[k].extend([loc for _, loc in v])


[]
[]
[]
['experiment1']
['experiment2']
['experiment3']
>>> d2
{'location2': ['experiment2', 'experiment3'], 'location1': ['experiment1', 'experiment2'], 'location3': ['experiment3', 'experiment4']}
```